# Simple animation via delayed drawing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, quartz-2d

I'm trying to implement some very simple line drawing animation for my iPhone app.  I would like to draw a rectangle on my view after a delay.  I'm using `performSelector` to run my drawing method.

```
-(void) drawRowAndColumn: (id) rowAndColumn
{
    int rc = [rowAndColumn intValue];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, currentColor.CGColor);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(rc * 100, 100, 100, 100);
    CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);

}
```

Which is then invoked via:

```
int col = 10;
[self performSelector:@selector(drawRowAndColumn:) 
           withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:col]
           afterDelay:0.2];
```

But it seems that when the `drawRowAndColumn:` message is actually sent, it no longer has access to a valid `CGContextRef`, as I get errors such as:

```
<Error>: CGContextAddRect: invalid context
```

If I replace the `performSelector` with a direct call to `drawRowAndColumn`, it works fine.  So my first idea was to also pass in the `CGContextRef` via the `performSelector`, but I can't seem to figure out how to pass multiple arguments at the same time (that's another good question.)

What's wrong with above code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just draw at any time like that. You need to implement the `drawRect:` method of UIView and put your drawing code in there.
To get `drawRect:` to fire you need to let Cocoa know that the view needs to be drawn. For that you can call `setNeedsDisplay`, or `setNeedsDisplayInRect:`.

Directly translating your attempt this way you'd call setNeedsDisplay using performSelector:withObject:afterDelay - but that's probably not a good way to do animation.

It depends what you're really trying to do - but you could consider, for example, putting your drawing code in `drawRect` as I suggested, but start the view hidden. You could then call setHidden:NO using performSelector to make it appear after a delay - or you could smoothly animate it in by starting not hidden, but with an alpha of 0, then change alpha to 1 within a UIView animation block (there's lots about this in the docs).

Comment: Using Core Animation, or the higher-level UIView based wrapper for it. That's what the last paragraph in my answer was talking about (the UIView animation block). You start an animation block, set some UIView properties, then commit the animation and the property changes will be animated in (you can control the timing etc).